# Can a J-2 visa be promoted to H1-B?

Tags: usa, j1-visas, h1b-visas

My wife has got admission in a PhD program in USA. So she's going to get J1 and I can get a J2 visa as her dependent. All J series visas have home residency requirements so I have to return when her J1 visa expires.

If I get a good job there while on J2, can I get my status changed to H1B so I won't have to leave a settled job when J1 expires?

Comment: The advice I got at the time, from international service at the University sponsoring my wife's J1 visa, was: do not get a J2 if you plan to find work, it's better to get your own visa.

Comment: "All J series visas have home residency requirements so I have to return when her J1 visa expires." Some J1 programs do, and some don't.

Comment: To answer your question, if the J1 has the 2-year home residency requirement, any J2 dependents also have the requirement, and cannot get H or L visas until accruing 2 years of physical presence in the home country, unless the requirement is waived.